# Вывод результата вычислений из одной формы в другую

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, label

Есть две формы: на Form2 располагаются textbox1, button1 и checkbox1-2. В ней пользователь вводит радиус окружности и выбирает при помощи checkbox режим вычислений (площадь/длина окружности).

На Form3 располагается label1, в котором необходимо вывести результат вычислений. Код Form2 следующий:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public int radius { get; set; }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = textBox1.Text.Length > 0; 
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            double S = Math.PI * Math.Pow(radius, 2);                
        }
    }

    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
        {
            double P = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radius = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

**Вопрос состоит в следующем:** как я могу передать результат вычислений в label1 (Form3) после нажатия на кнопку button1(Form2)?

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто вот пример :
в форму 3 в конструктор добавить

```
private int _radius;
    public Form3(int radius)
    {
        _radius = radius;
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

в форме который вызываете форму3

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radius = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            Form3 s = new Form3(radius);
            s.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: У меня проблема в том, что когда нажимается кнопка, результат вычислений только сохраняется, сама Form3 еще не открывается. После этого пользователь переходит в Form1 и уже там решает, открывать форму Form3 или нет (из меню)

Comment: так сохраните результат куда угодно а потом вызовите форму как показано